# Выдает не правильное разрешение экрана

Tags: c++

```
    int SysWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
int SysHeigth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);



int main()
{
  
  cout << SysWidth << '\n' << SysHeigth << '\n';
  sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(SysWidth, SysHeigth), "Ray trasing", sf::Style::Titlebar | sf::Style::Close);
  
  window.setFramerateLimit(60);
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Выдает просто 1536 на 864, хотя должно быть 1920 на 1080

Comment: SM_CYFULLSCREEN и по иксу

Comment: Похоже, что приложение не DPI-aware, а включено масштабирование.

Answer (score 0):

У Вас скейлинг работает, в 1,25 раза. Посмотрите в этом направлении